# Non-stringly typed reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, strong-typing

Given the following code..

```
public static class Simulate
{
    public static bool Boolean(bool b)
    {
        return b;
    }

}
```

I wanted to check if the Expression uses this static function. I wanted to avoid [stringly-typed](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html) reflection, so as to make the code more refactoring-friendly, that's why I'm trying to do the following, similar to [this](http://thecodejunkie.com/2010/04/strongly-typed-reflection-with-memberof.html). I tried the following code:

```
protected virtual Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
{

    if (m.Method == Simulate.Boolean)
```

But that doesn't work, so I tried this:

```
Expression<Action> fb = () => Simulate.Boolean(true);

string booleanName = fb.Body.ToString();

if (m.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(Simulate))
{
     if (m.Method.Name == booleanName)
```

However, expectedly, the above code returns **Boolean(true)**. But is there any way I can only get the **Boolean** string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access `MethodInfo` from the body of the expression, and then access it's name and it will return a string **Boolean**:

```
Expression<Action> fb = () => Simulate.Boolean(true);

var call = fb.Body as MethodCallExpression;

if (call != null)
    Console.WriteLine (call.Method.Name); //prints "Boolean" as a string
```

Comment: very fast! thanks very much! i'll accept it after two minutes(stackoverflow limitation)